# How to implement this type of search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm an SQL noobie and don't know how to properly title this question. If there's a name for this type of search, please feel free to edit the title, or post a comment and I'll change it.

I have a table called `movies`:

```
-------------------------
| id       | movie_name |
-------------------------
| 0        | Star Wars  |
| 1        | Casablanca |
-------------------------
```

Then a table called `movie_tag_options`, which contains all of the allowed tags for movies:

```
-------------------------
| id       | name       | 
-------------------------
| 0        | Action     |
| 1        | Sci-Fi     |
| 2        | Romance    |
-------------------------
```

Then a table called `movie_tags`, which is how tags are assigned to movies:

```
---------------------------------------
| id       | tag_option_id | movie_id |
---------------------------------------
| 0        | 0             | 0        |
| 1        | 1             | 0        |
| 2        | 2             | 1        |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to create a search feature where users can search for a movie by using tags, which I will translate into tag option IDs before doing the MySQL search.

So if someone searches for movies with the tags "Action" and "Sci-Fi," I will pass tag option IDs `0` and `1` to a search query, which should return the row for Star Wars.

How can I implement this type of search with MySQL?

Aside: I thought about storing the tag option IDs in a column in `movies` and then using Sphinx for searching, which would be fairly easy to do. I'm not sure which approach is better, though.

Comment: This type of query is just a straight JOIN.  You're linking rows together and taking anything that matches.  You can also do LEFT/RIGHT JOINS, OUTER JOINS and a few others.  Do a Google search for "sql types of JOINS", that should provide some helpful reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using a toxi schema

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tagmap bt, bookmark b, tag t
WHERE bt.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
AND b.id = bt.bookmark_id
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT( b.id )=3
```

Adjust that to what you need

http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas

Has more examples

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    movies.name
FROM
    movies
    ,movie_tag_options
    ,movie_tags
WHERE
    movie_tag_options.name = 'Sci-Fi'
    AND movie_tag_options.id = movie_tags.tag_option_id
    AND movie_tags.movie_id = movies.id
```

The above query will return you any movies with the tag Sci-Fi.
We are SELECTING any rows from movies, movie_tag_options and movie_tags WHERE the movie_tag_option is Sci-Fi AND Sci-Fi's ID exists on the movie_tags table AND that same movie_tags record has a movie_id that matches a record on the movies table.

Comment: To get Sci-Fi and Action, change
`movie_tag_options.name = 'Sci-Fi'`
to
`movie_tag_options.name IN('Sci-Fi', 'Action')`